# How can I build a human-scale Lego gun?

Tags: design

I would like to build Lego projectile weapons. Are there any designs available? Can one make an amunition magazine and self-reloading mechanism? Should I use rubberbands as ammunition or are there designs that fire Lego bricks?

Comment: You'll shoot your eye out!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are some Books available that include building-instructions (i don't own one of these, but i would choose the most current):

- [The BrickGun Book](https://www.brickgun.com/) (Book released in 2013, site has occasional updates as of December 2018 with more instructions)
- [Badass LEGO Guns](http://www.amazon.de/Badass-LEGO-Guns-Building-Instructions/dp/1593272847/ref=wl_it_dp_o_npd?ie=UTF8&coliid=I30SXQDXI2H25U&colid=1VYE0XU1E5BI7) (December 2010)
- [Weapons for LEGO Lovers](http://www.amazon.de/WEAPONS-LEGO-LOVERS-Xubor/dp/3000260625/ref=wl_it_dp_o_npd?ie=UTF8&coliid=I3U0GUHSZBE2II&colid=1VYE0XU1E5BI7) (February 2009)
- as [Joubarc](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/275/how-can-i-build-a-human-scale-lego-gun/279#279) said the at least 4 years old [Forbidden LEGO](http://www.amazon.de/Forbidden-LEGO-Models-Parents-Against/dp/1593271379/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1319791833&sr=8-1-spell) (July 2007)

to answer your question about magazines/reloading mechanisms: see [this youtube-video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H23HDHRVjpA) that shows such a mechanism in detail (although it's a bit hard to perceive details).

in addition the book about [LEGO Technic Simple Mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593272774) might also be interesting for you, if you want to try building a own gun instead of just "copying" from a detailed instruction.

Comment: There's a new one out: "[The BrickGun book](http://www.brickgun.com/)" - see [this review on Brickset](http://www.brickset.com/news/article/?ID=6566)

Answer (score 6):

The book "[Forbidden LEGO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271379)" has some, and you may also want to check [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=lego+gun) on the subject

Comment: I own this book and it's fairly outdated. The 9V 2-switch Battery box required to power the 'gun' is a rare find. It was last sold as part of the 4094 [Motor Movers](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=4094-1) set in 2003

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the model required modified and non-Lego pieces so it wasn't fully brick-built. Youtube is a good place to look for inspiration.

Answer (score 6):

There is a book called "[LEGO Heavy Weapons](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593274122)" by Jack Streat which is published by No Starch Press and can be bought for about £15 on Amazon.